# Start thread at springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to execute a java class (which contains a java thread I want to execute) after spring boot starts. My initial code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And here is is the code I want to execute at start:

```
public class SimularProfesor implements Runnable{

    // Class atributes

    // Constructor
    public SimularProfesor() {
        //Initialization of atributes
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call this thread? This is what I'm supposed to do:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        // Call thread (constructor must be executed too)
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't mess around with threads yourself. Create a `TaskExecutor` and register your class as a bean as well. Then add a `CommandLineRunner` which takes both the task and `TaskExecutor` to schedule the task. Also do you really need a thread?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am facing error mention in comment below, help will be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Don't mess around with threads yourself. Spring (and also plain Java) has a nice abstraction for that.

First create a bean of the type `TaskExecutor` in your configuration

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(); // Or use another one of your liking
}
```

Then create a `CommandLineRunner` (although an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` would also work) to schedule your task.

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner schedulingRunner(TaskExecutor executor) {
    return new CommandLineRunner() {
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            executor.execute(new SimularProfesor());
        }
    }
}
```

You could of course make also your own class managed by spring.

Advantage of this is that Spring will also cleanup the threads for you and you don't have to think about it yourself. I used a `CommandLineRunner` here because that will execute after all beans have bean initialized.

Comment: What if we need to inject dependencies into the Runnable class?

Comment: @mapm CommandLineRunner  is a bean so the dependencies will be injected as usual.

Comment: beans aren't injected

Comment: do not invoke constructor manually if you work in spring context, beans are NOT injected. I wonder why this answer so upvoted

Comment: If the object in case doesn't require anything to be injected there is nothing wrong with creating a new instance. Also this answer is for using a `TaskExecutor` not about proper dependency injection.

Answer (score 13):

- Main Class SpringBoot

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableAsync
  @Controller
  public class ...
  ```
- Example Class Controler

  ```
  import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
  import org.slf4j.Logger;
  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
  import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

  @Component
  public class ExecutorBase {

      private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExecutorBase.class);

      @Autowired
      private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
      @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

      private Boolean debug = true;

      @PostConstruct
      public void atStartup() {
          ClasseTaskRunn classeTaskRunn = applicationContext.getBean(ClasseTaskRunn.class);
          taskExecutor.execute(classeTaskRunn );
          if (debug) {
              log.warn("###### Startup ok");
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Example Class Task Runnable

  ```
  import org.slf4j.Logger;
  import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

  @Component
  @Scope("application")
  public class ClasseTaskRunn implements Runnable {

      private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClasseTaskRunn.class);

      @Autowired
      ClasseDAO classeDAO;

      @Override
      public void run() {
          longBackgorund();
      }

      protected void longBackgorund() {
          while (test) {
              if (debug) {
                  log.warn("###### DEBUG: " ... );
              }

              try {
                  Thread.sleep(10000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: you can use `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` annotation instead of `@PostConstruct` if you want to run the thread after the Spring context has been initialized