# Can springboot initialize a component as a thread?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have just looked into an old project which I can not discuss with the old developer. I have found a spring boot application with a class annotated as `@component`, which implements the `Runnable` interface, and has important code on its run method. However, when I launch the application, it does not go through that code. Am I missing something?

```
@Component
public Class A implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public run() {
    // never gets run
  }
}
```

I have not found any kind of `Thread` or `Executor` running this class.

Is spring boot supposed to find the Runnable components and run them on another `Thread` itself? Could this ever have worked?

Comment: [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37392048/833070). Going on that, it appears Spring Boot will not locate runnables and execute them without another method doing so

Comment: Alright, thank you very much @Draken I just wanted to make sure I was not missing anything. I guess it could never work :/ Ill try to fix it via the solution you refered :)