# Spring Boot property injection to Runnable from main function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a program that needs to start execution of four different `Runnable` classes.  These `Runnable` classes have configuration that I'd like them to grab from `application.properties`.

Here's a small set of code (minus the imports) that shows the concept of my problem.

`SampleApplication.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = taskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(/* This part is a mystery */);
    }

    @Bean
    public static ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        pool.setCorePoolSize(5);
        pool.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return pool;
    }
}
```

`SampleRunner.java`

```
@Component
public class SampleRunner implements Runnable {
    @Value("${value}")
    private String value;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("The value of this variable is " + value);
    }
}
```

`application.properties`

```
value="test value"
```

No matter what I've tried so far to create and execute this `Runnable`, I keep getting `The value of this variable is null`, I can't seem to get the value to actually "take".  I've tried doing a `new SampleRunner()` in that execute call, and I've also tried setting up the `SampleRunner` as a bean like the taskExecutor, and I've also tried defining the variable I need at the top level of SampleApplication to be passed in as an argument, but doing something like

```
@Value("${value}")
private static String test;
```

in SampleApplication just shows that variable as being null in the `main` function.  What's the right way in Spring Boot to create and use objects with injected data in a main function?

Comment: you need to read up on how spring boot works. When your main method is run and Springapplication.run is executed. The program vill start by building an ApplicationContext. This is done by scanning the main class and all classes below it in the file tree for all annotated classes. It will find all annotated classes and start instantiate them and run the bean annotated classes, during this process it will also inject in whatever vaues needed into anotated fields and constructors. You are creating the classes yourself, so Spring is not managing the beans and thus will not inject anything.

Comment: Right, I get that this is how Spring works, but if I’m needing to start multiple threads, I don’t think Spring will automagically kick off a Runnable into its own thread just because I put @Bean at the top, right? How do I bridge the gap of “Somehow Spring automatically fills in values for the setup of my Runnable” and “I execute that populated Runnable in its own thread?”

Comment: If you want to run code on startup there are things like the CommandRunner interface, that will run after startup, or the @Scheduled annotation that will run at set intervals

Comment: If you want to tweak the settings of the ExecutorService, you can specify these settings in your config file. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionProperties.html

Comment: Thanks, I think that information about CommandLineRunner and the ExecutorService is the kind of information I was looking for, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a POJO bean to configure your runner, e.g.:

```
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
    public AppConfig appConfig() {
        return new AppConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run1(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor, AppConfig appConfig) {
        return args -> taskExecutor.execute(() -> System.out.println(appConfig.getFoo()));
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run2(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor, AppConfig appConfig) {
        return args -> taskExecutor.execute(() -> System.out.println(appConfig.getBar()));
    }
```

This is more elegant than using the @Value annotation. Your implementation bean of CommandLineRunner can then use constructor injection to get the populated AppConfig instance.
In addition, the recommended way to execute a method in SpringBoot is to use the `CommandLineRunner` interface. A bean implementing this interface will be invoked at application startup.

The problem in your code is that the SampleRunner is not invoked in a spring context, so none of the annotations are processed.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37392048/1704634